# Publishing graph of unpublished work in paper

Tags: publications, phd, thesis

I am writing a paper which is building up on the work I have published earlier. It includes experimental results which were used to further develop the model.

To show that the model has improved I would like to include a graph of one of my experimental work showing the model predictions before and after the implementation of the improvements. The graph of the data has not been published and will be included in my PhD thesis. I would like to publish that data together with a similar series which I will use to evaluate my model (can can be used to evaluate similar models) in a separate paper.

Can I use the graph and reference it as my unpublished thesis. I have a thesis title already.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can state that " according to the (or based on yet) unpublished data collected in our lab or by xxx .....". It is widely used with no problem. (I am assuming you got permission from your advisor)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use this paper as an opportunity to make the first publication of the data? Why do you need to cite some other work for it when you can introduce it and publish it here?

Comment: If I use the data in this paper I have to write the material and method as well as all of the error analysis in this paper which is already very long. It is just within the page restriction.

Comment: The length restriction is probably a good reason to wait, but any reviewer who wants to see the methodology and error analysis is now going to have to wait until your thesis comes out to see it. That might hamper your credibility at the time of review of the paper.

Comment: I included the results in a separate document with the methodology and error analysis for the reviewers.